# How to make loop in python

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

ALL,

I have a following list:

["abc", "def", 'ghi"]

What I need to get from it is a string:

"abc,def,ghi"

There is a comma between first and second element, but not at the end of the string.

Unfortunately, Python does not have a construction like:

```
std::string str;
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    str += list[i];
    if( i != 2 )
        str += ",";
}
```

How do I do it in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of it in terms of a goal, not the way you'd do it in C++. You want to join the elements together:

```
','.join(elements)
```